# accessing char array from a separate class doc stack overflow error

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

I am new to java and i keep throwing this exception is there an error with the way i used mysWord.length or is the issue with .charAt(i)?

```
public static int setGuessdLetters(String mysWord)
{
    word.letters = new char[mysWord.length()];
    word.guesdletters = new char[mysWord.length()];

    for(int i = 0; i <= mysWord.length(); i++)
    {
        word.letters[i] = mysWord.charAt(i);
        word.guesdletters[i] = '_';
    }

    return(mysWord.length());
}
```

Error reads:

Please enter a word (14 character maximum): apple

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
at hangman.Hangman.setGuessdLetters(Hangman.java:206)
at hangman.Hangman.main(Hangman.java:258)
```

Java Result: 1

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)

Comment: It should be `i < mysWord.length()` instead of `i <= mysWord.length()` The index starts from `0` till `length-1`

Comment: Thank you, such a stupid thing to miss.

Comment: Its java which is making easier to debug with its SIOOBE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `less than equalto(<=)` with `less than(<)`.

Java array indexing begins from `0` to `length -1`.That is why you are getting `OutOfBoundsException`

```
for(int i = 0; i < mysWord.length(); i++)
    {
        word.letters[i] = mysWord.charAt(i);
        word.guesdletters[i] = '_';
    }
```